# im trying to use & in a where condition, but this condition is a date, i want to ask for the month and i dont know how to do that

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select cod_prestamo, cod_ejemplar, cod_libro,
  trunc (extract (month from fec_prestamo)/3) as "trimestre"

**where fec_prestamo &????**

from prestamo;
```

This is the code, I don't know how to ask for the month.

I tried with this but it obviously doesn´t work:

```
select cod_prestamo, cod_ejemplar, cod_libro,
  trunc (extract (month from fec_prestamo)/3) as "trimestre"
where fec_prestamo like '/&month/ '
from prestamo;
```

I need to answer with a month and then Oracle show the books that are registered in that month.

Comment: FROM comes before WHERE.

Comment: What is `&` supposed to mean?

Comment: "obviously doesn´t work" isn't helpful - tell us what happens and what error/result you get. Is `&month` a substitution variable, which your client (SQL\*Plus/SQL Developer/SQLcl) will prompt for? What format is it supplied in? And what data type is `fec_prestamo`? I'd guess you need to convert a string to a date and use that to search for a range, but it's unclear... Please provide some sample data, variable value and expected results for that - all as formatted text, not images please.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `fec_prestamo` is a `DATE` data type and that you are trying to use a substitution variable to pass in a month name and want to return three columns plus which quarter contains `fec_prestamo` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT cod_prestamo,
       cod_ejemplar,
       cod_libro,
       TO_CHAR(fec_prestamo, 'Q') as "trimestre"
FROM   prestamo
WHERE  TO_CHAR(fec_prestamo, 'fmMonth') = &month;
```

Then when you are prompted for the substitution variable you can enter: `'January'` (including the surrounding quotes).